# the file '/_controltemplates/.ascx' does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am making a SharePoint visual web part project for SharePoint 2013. The web part was working fine till yesterday but now it is giving following error.

> The file
>   '/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/VisualWebPartProject/Export/ExportUserControl.ascx'
>   does not exist

I have two solutions below which discuss this problem but I don't seem to apply solution in my case.

For e.g. solution 1 below discusses that I should open my ascx page there I have registered the user control and change CONTROLTEMPLATES to _CONTROLTEMPLATES. Problem is I don't have any such line in code to change.

Similarly in solution 2 below I don't know where I should change SharePoint version path which is /15/

Solution 1
http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/ascx-was-not-found/

Solution 2
http://blog.entos.at/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you picked **Visual Web Part (Farm Solutions Only)** from Add Item menu, you should see a cs file having same name with the web part. In that cs file there exists a constant with a comment above :

```
// Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/ProjectName/VisualWebPart2/VisualWebPart2UserControl.ascx";
```

You can clearly see the version (15) above.

Answer (score 0):

Register the user control using the following code: (Important: remove the TagName!)

```
<%@ Register
Assembly="BBB.XXXX.Webparts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b86a9e59abbaa56b"
Namespace="BBB.XXXX.Webparts.ControlTemplates.BBB.XXXX.Webparts"
TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

You can get the assembly from web.config
then register the control like this:

```
<uc1:WorkflowComments ID="WorkflowComments1" runat="server" />
```